# Trying to move expanding navbar from the right side to the left side

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

This is the HTML code for the expanding nav bar, it is from a template I am editing, I have been able to move the nav menu bar to the left and when I click on it, it expands on the right side which I am trying to fix and move it to expand on the left side too.

```
<div class="jumbotron home home-fullscreen" id="home">
    <div class="mask"></div>

<a href="" class="menu-toggle" id="nav-expander"><i class="fa fa-bars">
</i></a>
    <!-- Offsite navigation -->
    <nav class="menu">
        <a href="#" class="close"><i class="fa fa-close"></i></a>
        <h3> <a href="index.html"> spacecurb </a> </h3>
        <ul class="nav">
            <li><a data-scroll href="#home">Apartment</a></li>
            <li><a data-scroll href="#services">Hostel</a></li>
            <li><a data-scroll href="#portfolio">Room Rent</a></li>
            <li><a data-scroll href="#contact">Work Spaces</a></li>
            <li><a data-scroll href="#contact">hotels</a></li>
            <li><a data-scroll href="#contact">sign up</a></li>
            <li><a data-scroll href="#contact">log in</a></li>
            <li><a data-scroll href="#contact">about</a></li>
            <li><a data-scroll href="#contact">contact</a></li>
            <li><a data-scroll href="#contact">help</a></li>
            <li><a data-scroll href="#contact">add property</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="social-icons">
            <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

and this is the CSS code, I was able to move the expanding nav bar to the left, but it expands at the right

```
.menu-toggle{
position: absolute;
left: 15px; 
top: 15px;
font-size: 30px;
color: #fff;
}

.menu{
width: 300px;
display: block;
background: #333;
height: 100%;
top: 0;
right:-300px;
position: fixed;
z-index: 100;
text-align: center;
transition: right 0.4s;
}

.menu.nav-expanded{
right: 0;
}

.menu .close{
color: #fff;
margin-right: 10px;
margin-top:10px;
}
```

Comment: Running your code is resulting an empty page. Probably because of the position fixed. Anyways. Please provide working code so we can see your problem in action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have

```
.menu{
   width: 300px;
   right: -300px;
 }

.menu.nav-expanded{
  right: 0;
}
```

It means that your menu is out of screen (right) and when it expanded it come to page at position `right:0`.

Now if you want it go to left side in expand mode, remove `right:0` and set:

```
.menu.nav-expanded{
  left: 0;
}
```

To close menu by clicking on the normal screen add this jquery script block:

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function ()
    {
        $(document).click(function (e)
        {
            if (!$(e.target).hasClass('menu-toggle') && !$(e.target).closest('.menu').hasClass('menu'))
                $('.menu').removeClass('nav-expanded');
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: thank you it really helped, but i have another issue. when the navbar expands, i cannot close it by clicking on the normal screen, i can only close it by clicking the cancel (x) button. please do you have a solution to this?

Comment: You welcome, I changed my answer and added what you need.